# return struct in a mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping, bsc

**Hi, Im studing about mapping functions with structs. Have this:**

```
struct Persona{
    string Nombre;
    uint Edad;
}

mapping (uint => Persona) RelacionID;

function GuardarID(uint ID, string memory NombrePersona, uint EdadPersona) public{
    RelacionID[ID] = Persona(NombrePersona, EdadPersona);
}

function VerPersona(uint verID) public view returns(Persona){
    return RelacionID[verID];
}
```

**This line have problem:**

```
function VerPersona(uint verID) public view returns(Persona)
```

**Remix says:**

```
TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given.
  --> Estructura de datos/mappings.sol:45:57:
   |
45 |     function VerPersona(uint verID) public view returns(Persona){
   |                                                         ^^^^^^^
```

Any answer its good to me, thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you must return non-primitive datas such as: array, struct,...you must use keywords like memory, storage and calldata for define the data area where a variable'll store. In this case, you can use memory. You must change your smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract MintWithERC20 {
   struct Persona{
        string Nombre;
        uint Edad;
    }

    mapping (uint => Persona) RelacionID;

    function GuardarID(uint ID, string memory NombrePersona, uint EdadPersona) public{
        RelacionID[ID] = Persona(NombrePersona, EdadPersona);
    }

    function VerPersona(uint verID) public view returns(Persona memory){
        return RelacionID[verID];
    }
}
```

More information about data storage [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=memory#data-location).